# Error for Curl in docker file in .net core 6.0

Tags: docker, curl, .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0

I have modified the docker file as per the recommendations for .net core6.0.
However i face error in executing the curl url in the docker file.

The command is:

```
RUN curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/master/v0.12.4/64%20bit/libwkhtmltox.so --output libwkhtmltox.so
```

While deploying i get the error:

> ... docker build: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rdvojmoc/DinkToPdf/master/v0.12.4/64%20bit/libwkhtmltox.so --output libwkhtmltox.so]: exit code: 127

Can anyone please provide any clue?

How to execute the curl urls in docker file for .net core 6.0

Answer (score 4):

Chances are that `curl` isn't installed in the container. You could install it by adding the line

```
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl
```

This would be as in the Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y curl

CMD ["curl", "google.com"]
```

Comment: perfect answer - just what I needed